# Баг с сериализацией объектов в PHP 5.4

Tags: php

Выложил пример кода, который проявляет баг с сериализацией объектов в PHP 5.4

https://github.com/Smart-Core/php54-bugs

У самого опыта глубокого дебага нету :( по этому всё что могу сделать это выложить вот такую демку на Symfony2, там где встретил ошибку.

Может кто отзовётся и сможет собрать более компактный тест, чтобы отправить разработчикам баг-репорт?

Comment: А можно чуть поподробнее про баг? Ну или хотя бы скажи, что-где смотреть, а то не ясно. Не все пользуют Symfony2, кстати.Если не получится много, можно пару строк, на которых спотыкается?

Comment: Проблемма в том, что похоже что баг возникает где-то в недрах пхп притом магическим образом :) т.е. с эмулировать именно этот баг каким-то коротким кодом, мы с комрадами так и не смогли :( по этому пока просто имеем ввиду, что если в объекте есть циклический референс, то он может некорректно сериализоваться на 5.4 и просто не писать код таким образом ;) ну а дальше, просто ждать изменений у моря погоды :) может быть года через 2-4 этот нюанс и пофиксят :)

Comment: А баг ли? Можно текст ошибки?  
Кстати у меня такой код сериализуется нормально. Ошибок не вызвал на php 5.4:

    class a
    {
        public $toB;
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->toB = new b($this);
        }
    }
    
    class b
    {
        public $fromA;
        public function __construct($a)
        {
            $this->fromA = $a;
        }
    }    

и даже такой:

    class a
    {
        public $toA;
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->toA = $this;
        }
    }

    $a = new a();
    var_dump(serialize($a));

Answer (score 1):

Мне стало интересно и я увидел в Entity то что вы сериализуете Role объект,
поэтому вылетала ошибка:
Fatal error: Call to a member function getRole() on a non-object in home\www\php54-bugs-master\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\RoleHierarchy.php on line 47

Но когда я добавил в provider объект роли, ошибка исчезла.

```
#security.yml
providers:
        main:
            entity: { class: AcmeUserBundle:User, property: username }
            entity: { class: AcmeUserBundle:Role, property: name }
```

Но всё равно не понятно зачем роли сериализовать, лучше сделать как описано в "кук буке"

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html

Comment: да, всё верно, в данном случае нет смысла сериализовать что либо помимо id т.к. при аутентификации из сессии читается только id, а потом достаётся сущность пользователя из БД по этому id.

а ошибка с сериализацией была связана с циклическими объектами... хотя тут https://github.com/Smart-Core/php54-bugs/blob/master/src/Acme/UserBundle/Entity/User.php цикличности невижу, есть только вложенный объект... в общем я сделал вывод, что ненадо сериализовать вложенные объекты :) и больше не натыкался на этот баг :)